# Hierarchical clustering, problem with distance metric(Pearson, Manhattan, Euclidean)

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, euclidean-distance, pearson-correlation

I am facing this strange problem, that i am not able to figure out. With euclidean distance and manhattan distance(either their are standardized or not), clusters are divided in very strange way.
I attach examples.

```
D <- get_dist(samp, stand=T, method="euclidean")
AHC    <- hclust(D, method = "average")
AVcl_k3 <- cutree(AHC, k =3)
table(AVcl_k3)
AVcl_k4 <- cutree(AHC, k = 4)
table(AVcl_k4)
```

[image: Clusters i get standardizing data for the euclidean distance matrix]

Now, if I don't standardize the data, i face the same problem with euclidean distance.

```
 D <- get_dist(samp, stand=F, method="euclidean")
AHC    <- hclust(D, method = "average")
AVcl_k3 <- cutree(AHC, k =3)
table(AVcl_k3)
AVcl_k4 <- cutree(AHC, k = 4)
table(AVcl_k4)
```

[image: Clusters i get not standardizing data for the euclidean distance matrix]

If i indeed use pearson correlation, either i standardize or not, i get decent clusters.

[image: Clusters i get standardizing the data with PEARSON method]

```
 D <- get_dist(samp, stand=T, method="pearson")
AHC    <- hclust(D, method = "average")
AVcl_k3 <- cutree(AHC, k =3)
table(AVcl_k3)
AVcl_k4 <- cutree(AHC, k = 4)
table(AVcl_k4)
```

If i don't standardize the data with pearson method, i get different clusters but still decent well divided ones. I know there is a difference if i standardize the data or not.

Can somebody help me figuring out why this is happening? I've read in other questions that euclidean and pearson, if standardized, they can be reduced to cosine similarity.

In all the codes and images i am just showing the hierarchical clustering with the average linkage, but in general this phenomenon happens with all the other linkages (single and complete).

The dataset i'm using is the retail dataset, made of 500k istances x 8 variables. It's on UCI machine learning dataset. My clustering analysis is based on Recency, Frequency, Monetary variables extracted from this dataset after some manipulation. I must include this detail: there are outliers, given by the fact that they represent few customerID who are those who spend the most and most frequent. So they can't be removed(with the pearson correlation, i get a cluster formed by 23 observations, and it's these customers only).
Thanks in advance for the help

I've tried reading some other solved questions online, books and papers, but didn't help

Comment: When you get the classes with size `1, 2, 2000` vs `1999, 1, 3` The result is the same. But it has not been clustered.

Comment: Yeah, but i need to understand why i get such small clusters with euclidean distance. Even increasing the number of k to (for example) 16, still keeps doing it.

Comment: First euclidean is not a good distance measure in high dimenisons. I do not know how bid your data is in terms of p. Also, maybe your data is just not deparable in euclidean space

Comment: Considering all the manipulation, i end up with a dataset of 4000 p observations x 3 variables. 
But if both euclidean and Pearson, if stand=T, are reduces to cosine, why pearson works but euclidean doesn't? This is what i don't understand

Comment: You have several outliers that the is causing the uneven clustering euclidean/ Manhatten distances.  Cut into more groups and then manually merge the smallest groups together.  It all depends on what your end goal is.  Maybe this will help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/408438/difference-between-euclidean-pearson-geodesic-and-mahalanobis-distance-metrics.

Comment: Thanks, but the answer into the link is not relevant to understand why this is happening. Even Pearson method is said to be sensitive to outliers, but still performs something decent. Merging the groups into r is possible with which command?